# Find nearest location from latitude and longitude from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Data

```
dloc1 = {'lat': [41.75, 41.87,41.77], 'long': [-87.62, -87.74,-87.69]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dloc1)
dloc2 = {'Name': [a,c,b], 'lat': [41.830, 41.90,41.97], 'long': [-87.62, -87.69,-88.65]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dloc2)
```

from df1, I want to find the name of the nearest location in df2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
print(df2['Name'][df2[['lat', 'long']].sub(df1).abs().sum(1).idxmin()])
```

Output:

```
a
```